# How to pass a pair of values to Table function?

Tags: functions

I define a function like this:

```
ϕ[t_,ϕ0_,ϕ1_]:=ϕ0+ϕ1/ArcSin[0.97] ArcSin[0.97 Sin[2Pi f(t-0.25/f)]]/.f->30
```

which generate:

$$ \phi (t)=0.754586 \times \text{$\phi $1} \times\sin ^{-1}(0.97 \sin (60 \pi  (t-0.00833333)))+\text{$\phi $0}$$

Then I want to generate two function with (ϕ0,ϕ1)=(0,10) and (ϕ0,ϕ1)=(100,200) with `Table` function like bellow:

```
Table[ϕ[t], {{ϕ0, ϕ1}, {{0, 10}, {100,200}}}]
```

But it doesn't work.

How to manage it ?

Comment: `ϕ[t, ##] & @@@ {{0, 10}, {100, 200}}` should work. Is that what you're looking for? If the syntax is unfamiliar, check out `Apply` and `SlotSequence` in the docs.

Comment: If you really want to use `Table` you can "replace one of the @" in Martin's answer: `Table[ϕ[t, ##] & @@ pp, {pp, {{0, 10}, {100, 200}}}]`

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thank you very much. I've learnt a new skill !

Comment: @unlikely Frankly speaking, this method seems the same with using `Rule`.

Comment: @BlacKow Thanks for sharing. Your method shares something in common with MikeLimaOscar's .

Comment: @PureLine Honestly I didn't understood what you was asking for, so I had to guess...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing your initial function definition slightly makes using `Table` easier and saves having to mess around with `SlotSequence`, `Function`,  `Apply`, etc.  For example, I would define `ϕ` as:

```
ϕ[t_, {ϕ0_, ϕ1_}] := ϕ0 + ϕ1 / ArcSin[0.97] ArcSin[0.97 Sin[2Pi f(t - 0.25 / f)]] /. f -> 30
```

Such that the parameters are paired in a single argument.  Then you can use:

```
Table[ϕ[t, ϕ01], {ϕ01, {{0, 10}, {100,200}}}]
```

which I think is "more natural".

Incidentally, the replacement of `f` occurs every time the function `ϕ` is evaluated which is inefficient.  It would be better to wrap the RHS of your definition in `Evaluate`.